# How do you use provision a centOS vm on spinnaker?

Tags: centos, spinnaker

Out of the box spinnaker does not come with centOS as an option when creating a pipeline. How do you make centOS an option and complete both the bake and deploy steps?

Answer (score 1):

i had this same issue.  after digging around i found that you actually have to edit the Rosco config.
https://github.com/spinnaker/rosco/blob/master/rosco-web/config/rosco.yml

you'll need to make your own entry.  i also found that even after adding a centos base image, packer still had problems w/ RPM because of the install_packages.sh provisioning script.  its missing RPM support in the AMI Spinnaker says to use in its documentation.  the one im using is here...

https://github.com/spinnaker/rosco/blob/master/rosco-web/config/packer/install_packages.sh

Comment: Can you please share what exactly you changed in both rosco.yml and intall_packages ?